# Using google ml engine prediction for a sci-kit learn model which needs additional modules

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, google-cloud-ml, lightgbm

I have my pipeline defined in a separate file `model.py`

```
class TextSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.field]

class NumberSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[[self.field]]

text_features = Pipeline([
    ('selector', TextSelector(field='text')),
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5, max_df=0.25, ngram_range=(1, 1))),
    ('decomposer', TruncatedSVD(n_components=300))
])

features = FeatureUnion([
    ('text_features', text_features),
    ('other_feature', NumberSelector(field='other')),
])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', features),
    ('lgbm', LGBMClassifier(max_depth=-1, n_estimators=300,
                            learning_rate=0.1, n_jobs=2,
                            class_weight='balanced'))
])
```

To train and dump the model

```
from model import pipeline

clf = pipeline.fit(X, y)
joblib.dump(clf, 'model.joblib')
```

In order to load the model, the script need access `model.py`. Where should I put this file when using google ml engine?

I tried

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=/path/to/models  --json-instances=input.json --framework=SCIKIT_LEARN
```

with `model.py` inside `path/to/models` directory.

The error

> cloud.ml.prediction.prediction_utils.PredictionError: Failed to load
>   model: Could not load the model:
>   /path/to/the/model/model.joblib. No module named 'model'.
>   (Error code: 0)

Another question is that is it possible to use `lightgbm` instead on ml-engine prediction?

Comment: Can you write how you are specifying the flags for [gcloud ml-engine local predict](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/local/predict)? Also bear in mind when using Python 3.x you need to specify the Python version and Cloud ML Engine runtime version to [create model version](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/quickstart#create_a_model_resource). By default Cloud ML Engine v1.0 is used but for Python 3.x [v1.9](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/runtime-version-list#supported_cloud_ml_engine_runtime_versions) needs to be specified.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/) available machine learning frameworks are TensorFlow, scikit-learn and XGBoost.

Comment: Hi @Yurci see the updated question. I'm using the scikit learn API of lightgbm, so as long as there is a way to install additional packages, i.e.  `pip install lightgbm`, it should work the same as only using scikit learn

Comment: Have you created your model.joblib file?

Comment: This feature is not currently supported, but will be very soon (as an alpha). Please write to cloudml-feedback@google.com if you would like to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Google recently launched "Custom Prediction Routines", which let you load different packages or call your own methods in predictions: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/custom-prediction-routines

Comment: Anything else you can add?